# Two questions about array: select an item and compare Date

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have something like this:

```
var cars = [
{car:"01", color:"red", date: Date("Sep 23, 2013 12:00:00")},
{car:"02", color:"blue", date: Date("Sep 24, 2013 12:00:00")},
{car:"03", color:"green", date: Date("Sep 25, 2013 12:00:00")},
{car:"04", color:"yellow", date: Date("Sep 26, 2013 12:00:00")},
{car:"05", color:"purple", date: Date("Sep 27, 2013 12:00:00")}];
```

and I want to: 1) select an item `car:"03"` for example, how do I do this? I thought of doing something like this, just for testing, but this didn't work out:

```
$(cars).each(function(i,el) {
    console.log($(this).car);
});
```

and 2) is this valid to compare this kind of `Date` in the array to real current `Date`? for example:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
if ( currentDate < Date ) { ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't use car:01 or car:02 and so on. There is already key on every object in your array, so you can access car: 03 by just getting cars[2] (because keys start with 0 not 1)

Comment: Thanks. Following your logic, tried to do `console.log($(this).car[i]);` but this didn't work out too... I'm using "01", "02", "03" etc not as an index, but as a car number. it may be 10th in the array, but "33" as a number next to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look for the property `car` on each object and compare it's value to the value you are searching for

Also use `$.each()` to iterate arrays or objects instead of `$.fn.each()` which is really intended for use with element selectors

```
$.each(cars, function(i, el) {
    if(el.car === '03'){
        console.log(el);
    }        
});
```

There are other native array methods you can use like `Array.prototype.find()` but i stayed with `$.each` to maintain consistency with question code

As for the date comparison ...yes you can directly compare date objects using `<` or `>`

Comment: Thank you very much, Charlietfl! Could you please tell me how may I take the value of the "car"? For example if I don't know the value, I won't be able to compare it, so I would need to check it and get it somehow.

Comment: Take it from where though?

Comment: From the array of "cars". For example, if for some reason I don't know exactly what is the "car" number, or "color"... how could I get this?

Comment: well you need to know one property value (or be able to get it from some sort of event)  in order to get another.

Comment: Ok Charlietfl, thanks